# Lodash - Search if String contains a word that start with

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter, lodash

I have an array of elements (let's say a list of fitness trainings).

I have a search bar, and I would like to create **a search feature to find a specific training**.

I know how to filter the array to:

1. Keep trainings where **name start with *string typed in the search bar***

   ```
   array = array.filter(function(item) {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchFilter.toLowerCase());
   });
   ```

> Exemple: Search = "El"...
>
> Results -> `["Elizabeth", "Elisa"]`
>
> Results not fetched -> `["Open Elios"]`

2. Keep trainings where **name contains *string typed in the search bar***

   ```
   array = _.filter(array, function(item) {
      return _.includes(item.name.toLowerCase(), searchFilter.toLowerCase());
   });
   ```

> Exemple: Search = "El"...
>
> Results -> `["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"]`

But it's not what I would like:

3. Keep training where **name contains words starting with *string typed in the search bar***

> Exemple: Search = "El"...
>
> Results -> `["Elizabeth", "Open Elios"]`
>
> Results not fetched -> `["Camel"]`

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the thrid?

Comment: @adiga first: 1st = if a string contains multiple words, only the first one is concerned by the search. 3rd = if a string contains multiple words, all the words are concerned by the search

Comment: @KevinB you want values like `hello-el` to be included in filtered result ?

Comment: Not especially, only with space is great

Comment: @CodeManiac Although it's not very clear, but I think the OP wants as he mentions `name contains words starting with string typed in the search bar`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex for that, something like:

```js
const result = ["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"].filter(v => /\bel/i.test(v));
console.log(result);
```

The important part is `\b` which means word boundary, basically this expression `/bel` is testing if the value contains something that starts with a word boundary and is fallowed by `el`.

Here is a complete example that constructs the regex from a string:

```js
const array = ["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"];
const searchFilter = 'El';
const escapeRegExp = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

const result = array.filter(value => new RegExp(`\\b${escapeRegExp(searchFilter)}`, "i").test(value));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The only gotcha here is that it will also catch hyphenated words Open-elio would also be captured by this regex. Not necessarily a good or a bad thing, it depends on your desired behaviour.

Comment: @CalIrvine not only hyphen any non word character will match such as `hello@el` or anything which is not `digit, alphabet or _`, but that's totally based on OP's requirement

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dynamic regex with a word boundary `\b` using [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor

```js
function filter(arr, word) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}`, 'i');
  return arr.filter(n => regex.test(n))
}

console.log(filter(["Elizabeth", "Elisa", "Open Elios", "Camel"], "El"))
```

Comment: I think using `\b` is not safe as it will match values like `hello-el` too, although i am not sure OP wants it or not

Answer (score 1):

Apart form regex, you could also apply `filter` twice with the last one returning a boolean value for the filter of the current string to be included.

```js
var search_string = 'eli';
search_string = search_string.toLowerCase();
const arr = ["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"];
const result = arr.filter(value => value.split(' ').filter(token => token.toLowerCase().startsWith(search_string)).length > 0);
console.log(result);
```

**Update:**

As suggested by @Titus in the comments, you can also use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to filter data which would immediately return true if it finds a token which starts with your search string, instead of collecting all tokens in a filter that would start with your search string.

```js
var search_string = 'eli';
search_string = search_string.toLowerCase();
const arr = ["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"];
const result = arr.filter(value => value.split(' ').some(token => token.toLowerCase().startsWith(search_string)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The second time, instead of `.filter(....)` you can use [`.some(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) so you won't have to check all the words or check the result's length.

Comment: I just realized that it's not working when there is a space within the String :/ ... For example if I write "Open E" I got 0 result back

Comment: @KevinB Can you let me know more about `Open E` ? What was the search value and what is the set of words you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to build a dynamic pattern based on value

```
(?:^|[ ])${value}
```

- `(?:^|[ ])` - Match start of string or space
- `${value}` - dynamic value coming from search bar

```js
let search = (value) => {
  const reg = `(?:^|[ ])${value}`
  const regex = new RegExp(reg,'gi')
  const result = ["Elizabeth", "Open Elios", "Camel"].filter(v => regex.test(v));
  return result
}

console.log(search('el'));
```